# Search and replace on a file using Paramiko SFTP client

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I have a file on an SFTP server to which I can connect to open and write to. However I need to search for a piece of text and replace it with another. Is this possible using Paramiko SFTP?

The code I have looks like this

```
for filename in s.sftp.listdir():
    file = sftp.open(filename,'ar+')
    line = file.readable()
    file = file.write("Test Test Test")
    file = sftp.close()
```

I have tried to use the sftp.replace() but when i run it i get the following error

```
    file = s.sftp.replace("15062018", "11092018")
```

> AttributeError: 'SFTPClient' object has no attribute 'replace'

Where the first date is the date currently in the file and the second date is the one I want to replace it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there's no `SFTPClient.replace` in Paramiko.

You have to read file contents to a variable, perform replace, and write back.

```
for filename in sftp.listdir():
    with sftp.open(filename, 'r+') as file:
        contents = file.read()
        contents = contents.replace("15062018", "11092018")
        file.seek(0)
        file.write(contents)
```

Obviously this is can be quite inefficient for large files. Also if a replacement string is shorter than an original (not this case), you need to truncate the file after writing the contents back.